# Transfer Google Tasks to Google Reminders

Tags: google-calendar, google-tasks, google-calendar-reminders

I have a couple of Tasks in the old-style Google Tasks "Calendar". I'd like to transfer them to (and start using) the new "Reminders" feature.

Is there a way for me to do that without cutting and pasting from one to the other?

Answer (score 3):

At this time the Google Apps (Calendar, Gmail, Keep, Now ) don't have either a user interfaces' command or API's class for the **new reminders** to convert a Google task to a Google reminder.

An alternative could be the use of a user script<sup>1</sup> that use the Google Tasks API or Google Apps Script.

Notes:

- <sup>1</sup> A user script is a code snippet that changes the look and feel or behaviour of a website through the web browser developer console, bookmarklets, or browser extensions like Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey.

**References**

- [Create & change reminders in Google Calendar - Google Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Desktop)
- [Reminders - Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders)
- [Tasks API - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/)
- [Tasks Service - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/tasks)
- [Is there a public Google API to access reminders set in Google Now or Google Keep? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728176/is-there-a-public-google-api-to-access-reminders-set-in-google-now-or-google-kee)